# How can I snap an object with curve modifier to a vertex?

Tags: modifiers, objects, vertices, snapping, path

I need your valuable help in something I am stuck on...

As you can see in the image below, a curve modifier has been added to the selected object to follow a specific path. What I'm trying to do, but I don't know if this is even possible, is to snap point "A" of the object to point "B", while moving the object.

I tried to move my object in edit mode, with the "Active Element" activated in "Transform Pivot Point" but as you will see in the second image, it "locks" in wrong point.

Any idea;

Thank you for your time!!!

[image]

[image]

**Edit:** Here is a blend file of what I am trying to do... [image]